# Office 365 - didn't ask me which drive to install onto - how can I move it?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office

I just installed Office 365.

I expected it to ask me where I wanted it installed - it didn't, just slapped it into '%PROGRAMFILES%'

How can I move it to some location other than the C: drive ?

Also I only wanted Excel. Is there some way I can just install Excel ?